# How can I delete the no point area in python matploylib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[image]

def graph_meas_period(columns, opt, file):
# plot graph
new_df = df[["dateTime"] + columns]
new_df.plot(x="dateTime", y=columns, figsize=(15*3*cm, 5*3*cm), color=['black', 'blue', 'red'])
xmin = df["FormattedTime"].iloc[0]
xmax = df["FormattedTime"].iloc[-1]

```
legend = plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.8, -0.05), ncol=3, columnspacing=15)
# plt.xlim(xmin, xmax)
# plt.xlim([df["FormattedTime"].iloc[1], df["FormattedTime"].iloc[-1]])
# set legend text
for col in columns:
    if "1" in col:
        color = 'black'
    elif "2" in col:
        color = 'blue'
    elif "3" in col:
        color = 'red'
    else:
        color = 'black'

    legend.get_texts()[columns.index(col)].set_text(opt.split(" ")[0] + " " + col)
    legend.legendHandles[columns.index(col)].set_color(color)


# setup graph
# plt.xlim(min(), max())
plt.xticks(fontsize=6)
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel("")
plt.ylabel(opt)

save_to_png(plt, file, opt)

idx = new_df.index
num_of_rows = len(idx)
return num_of_rows
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the right and left limits in `xlim` to match the first and last x values the array that you are plotting.

Here is an example.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

samples=np.arange(100)
values=np.random.random(100)

plt.plot(samples, values)
```

This code example returns the following image:
[image]

Adding `plt.xlim(left=0, right=100)` changes the plot to:

[image]

**EDIT:**

This fix also works with datetime types.

For instance, consider the following script:

```
    import datetime 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
numdays = 5
base = datetime.datetime.today()
date_list = [base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(numdays)]

plt.plot(date_list, np.random.random(5))
plt.xlim(left=date_list[0], right=date_list[-1])
```

This code returns:

[image]

Comment: but the x axis in this case is in time format (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss)
and different case have different date
How can we automate the process?

Comment: This solution also works with x-axis values in datetime format. I edited my answer to address this case.